# Oracle CASE failing with multiple columns in Else clause

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle below query is working fine with single column but when I tried to put multiple columns it fails, Actually my requirement is to Exit SQL query if there is no records in particular table and its complex inner query (below is simplified problem description) and I cannot use PL/SQL block, please suggest.

```
SQL> select 
         case when (select count(*) from bl1_charge_adj where rownum=1) = '1' then ( select customer_id  from customer) 
         else 44 END as ee
     from dual;
```

```
EE
----------
44
```

```
SQL> select 
         case when (select count(*) from bl1_charge_adj where rownum=1) = '1' then ( select customer_id,DL_UPDATE_STAMP from customer) 
         else (1,2) END 
     from dual
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: This is correct.  `case` is a scalar expression, meaning that it returns one value.  Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: My requirement is to exit immediately from complex SQL query if one of the 4 tables involve in query is empty (as i cannot use pl/sql so i am trying to achieve this using CASE , please suggest if there is any other way i can do it using SQL )

Comment: Please, do not clarify questions with comments, but edit the question instead

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select customer_id, DL_UPDATE_STAMP
from customer
where exists (select 1 from bl1_charge_adj)
union all
select 1, 2
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from bl1_charge_adj);
```

Comment: Actually in your case `select customer_id, DL_UPDATE_STAMP
from customer` with run in any case , i want this Customer query to not run at all if bl1_charge_adj is empty , In Real scenario Customer query is big query which is unnecessary burning CPU in Production and i know it will not return result in last, as table bl1_charge_adj is empty

Comment: @user2993724 . . . This is actually more efficient than your version.  The `where` clause is evaluated to determine if any rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select nvl(c.customer_id, 1), nvl(c.DL_UPDATE_STAMP, 2)
from ( select count(*) as c from bl1_charge_adj where rownum=1) d
left outer join customer c on d.c = 1;
```

I suspect it would be better done by changing the `count(*)` to something else if the `bl1_charge_adj` table is big.

Comment: This will have amusing behavior is `customer` has more than 1 row and `bl1_charge_adj` has no rows.

Comment: Good point, I am assuming that there should be some where condition on the customer id somewhere such that the customer bit returns one row. Otherwise, the original question doesn't make sense either. Maybe the rownum bit should go from the count(*) select.